# Java : Bound mismatch error

Tags: java

I'm learning Java and I have to create a program that implements an interface defined by the teacher to pratice ADT (using ArrayList). I got errors that I don't understand maybe new explanations can help me.

**Interface :**

```
public interface A<T extends C> { ... }
```

**Class signature in error :**

```
public class AImpl<T> implements A<T> { /*Bound mismatch error*/ ... }
```

**JUnit test class**

```
//Declaration
A<Alphabet> alphaList;

//in setUp()
alphaList = new AImpl<Alphabet>;

// in one method
alphaList.size();  /* The method size() is undefined for the type A<Alphabet> */
```

Note that Alphabet is given by the teacher too and there's the signature :

```
public class Alphabet implements C { ... }
```

Can someone help to point out where is my errors with some explanations ?

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean with [ADT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADT)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the Type in the interface (T) is bound to extend C, therefore you are saying it must inherit from C. In your class which gives the implementation you don't specify any bounds on the Type of parameter T. The key to this is that T in the first example is not the same as T in the second, and therefore you must specify the bounding again. The following code should solve your problem with the bounding issue.

Interface:

```
public interface A<T extends C> { ... }
```

Implemtation:

```
public class AImpl<T extends C> implements A<T> { /*Bound mismatch error*/ ... }
```

Comment: So AImpl<T extends C> = A<T> because <T> means <T extends C> ?

Comment: Basically yes, the problem is that T in one case is not T in the other. They are differnet generic types so you need to make sure the bounding applies to both. Admittedly this does seem like it should be handled byt the fact that you are implementing the interface with the constraint there, but for some reason it generates a compilation error unless you are explicit about it.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem declare `AImpl` with assurance, that generic type would extend `C`:

```
public class AImpl<T extends C> implements A<T> { }
```